# Quality of flash object

Tags: flash

I have embedded a flash object in my html page.
But the clarity is not as good as expected.

http://www.saraswaticlasses.net/trimax/

I used Camstudio to generate it and it shows correctly if played from within that software.

Comment: Are you sure the aspect ratio is maintained? Post the resolution of original video and the flash video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a "quality=high" attribute to your embed tag. and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same scale? Did you record and export for width="1024" height="768"? Are there quality settings in camtasia you can adjust? Did you use h264 video? Check those things.

It looks to me like the video is recorded for a lower or higher resolution, and then you're rescaling in the browser.